# Copying content files in GruntJS?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm pretty new to GruntJS - how can I copy my HTML in a src directory into a working directory? Images? CSS? I can't copy the whole folder because it might have coffee files, JS files etc. How can I setup my project to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) and its [processContentExclude option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#processcontentexclude). Should be able to just pass an array of [*.coffee, *.whatever].